# How to solve for a second degree term in an equation with SymPy

Tags: python, math, sympy, solver

My equation is ax = ln(e<sup>c-b</sup>/y)
How can I find what x*y equals in python? I've tried using SymPy.solve, but it doesn't allow me to solve for a term. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should explain it better. If you want to solve for `a` term like `a(x,y)` is simple ---> `x, y, a  = symbols('x y a')` then `eqn = a*x - log( exp(c-b) / y )` and finally `solution = solve(eqn, a)` . The log and exp methods must be from sympy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you solve for `y = f(x)` then `y*x = x*f(x)`. So these two steps in SymPy are:

```
>>> from sympy.abc import a,b,c,x,y
>>> from sympy import solve, Eq
>>> solve(Eq(a*x , ln(exp(c-b)/y)),y)
[exp(-a*x - b + c)]
>>> _[0]*x # == y*x
x*exp(-a*x - b + c)
```

You *can* solve for any subexpression, but when it is not a symbol, it will be interpreted literally as if you solved for `u` after replacing the sub-expression with `u`:

```
>>> solve(x*y - 1/x, x*y)
[1/x]
```

In your expression there is no `x*y` so that's why an attempt to naively solve for it fails.